# Nx CLI run many command is not working for multiple apps

Tags: monorepo, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I have tried using Nx in an attempt to make use of Monorepos. I have been facing an issue to serve multiple apps via `nx run-many` command. Can anyone correct me if I'm doing something wrong?

Command used: `nx run-many --target=serve --all`

I can see the Nx Console logging all the available apps but only running one

```
>  NX  Running target serve for projects:
  - app1
  - app2
———————————————————————————————————————————————
> nx run app1:serve
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? What I do is simply run "ng serve", this builds all apps in their respective ports properly, but I'm having issues with the watcher, is not detecting changes in anything than the HOST application, so every time I change something, I need to rebuild all, can't find a solution yet.

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

```
nx run-many --parallel --target=serve --projects=frontend,backend
```

Comment: That command should work but ports conflict when I have multiple nest.js apps.

Answer (score 12):

```
nx run-many --target=serve --all --maxParallel=100
```

The default value for --maxParallel is three, it means runs tasks in batches of three by default.

Additional, Exclude few apps to not serve then.

```
nx run-many --target=serve --all --maxParallel=100 --exclude=app-name
```

[Github](https://www.github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/2088#issuecomment-557618582)

Comment: Can you please [edit] that in to your answer? Treat comments as if they can be deleted at any time.

Comment: On my case, I created the applications by specifying the ports, so I might not have the same scenario than the OP, but when I ran this solution it seems to be working fine, and also it solves the problem that otherwise, it will not watch the changes from remote apps. Yet i'm not sure why if you specify maxParallel=1 or 3, it only starts 1 or 3 apps, so it's not really parallel, it's more how many apps should run (or it's a bug)

Comment: see this https://nx.dev/reference/nx-json#tasks-runner-options

Answer (score 8):

This happens due to port overriding, if you have multiple frontend apps for example they will run on the same port.
You can manage every project configuration in ***project.json*** file, and there you can handle different port for every project.

example:

```
"serve": {
  "executor": "@nrwl/web:dev-server",
  "options": {
    "buildTarget": "react-todo:build",
    "hmr": true,
    "port": 3001
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "buildTarget": "react-todo:build:production",
      "hmr": false
    }
  }
},
```

this is a react config in *(**apps/<Your_Project_Name>/project.json**)*

Answer (score 5):

Update solution in 9/2022.

1. go to `package.json` adding this script that allow us to run many project with only one command

   `"all": "npx nx run-many --target=serve --all --maxParallel=100"`
2. inside `apps` folder, there are several application, and go to their `package.json`, and edit `targets -> serve -> options like this sample

   ```json
     "options": {
       "buildTarget": "your app name:build",
       "hmr": true,
       "port": 4201 // adding this
     },
   ```

Comment: I tried the maxPrallel and it worked, and don't keep any other parallel related property flags.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the serving port by editing `package.json`

```json
"serve": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/web:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "buildTarget": "admin-web:build",
        "port": 4220,
        "hmr": true
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "buildTarget": "admin-web:build:production",
          "hmr": false
        }
      }
    }
```

After that you can run `nx run-many`

```sh
nx run-many --parallel --target=serve --projects=frontend,backend
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, Remix uses a hardcoded 8002 port for file watcher. When running two or more remix apps at once, either one of the apps (which was started later) would have an error accessing the file server port.
To override, add a `.env` or `.env.local` file in your respective app directory and add the environment variable `REMIX_DEV_SERVER_WS_PORT`.

```
apps/
 - app1
      .env.local -> REMIX_DEV_SERVER_WS_PORT=8003
 - app2
      .env.local -> REMIX_DEV_SERVER_WS_PORT=8004
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
nx run-many --help

...

      --parallel           Max number of parallel processes [default is 3]                                                [string]
```

```
nx run-many --parallel=4 --target=dev --output-style=stream --projects=@example/one,@example/two,@example/three,@example/four
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest [NX documentation](https://nx.dev/packages/nx/documents/run-many):

```
nx run-many --targets=serve -p project1 project2 pj3 pj4 --parallel=4
```

> Also instead of `nx` in terminal you can use `node_modules/.bin/nx` or `npx nx`